# find local maxima and their percentiles on a signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, max

i have a signal, and want to find its local maxima with MATLAB, find their amplitude, sort these from smallest to biggest, and select the 75th percentile of the set.

How can i do this?

**75th percentile: means the specific element of the set that 75% of the data are equal or smaller that this. Example: if we have values from 0 to 100, 75 is the 75th percentile.

Comment: Have you tried something, do you have an example given as input and what you expect as output?

Comment: is your signal 1D (vector) or 2D (array)? also, if you want the "amplitude of the local max" you most probably have complex-valued entries? Ps. Welcome to SO. Sometimes the answers are as easy as going through the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For real-vaued, vector (1D) signals you can use [findpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) from Signal Processing Toolbox to find local maxima, and specify parameters such as peak distance or maxima threshold.

For complex-valued signals you can apply `findpeaks()` to the magnitude of the signal through `abs()`.

If you need to sort values you can use [sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sort.html) and [prctile](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/prctile.html) to calculate percentiles from a vector of values.

Comment: thanks dear, i used pks = findpeaks(yy,'sortstr','ascend') to sort them too.

Comment: @ Etienne i have a signal, i want to find the ampitude of the local max, not the index of them

Comment: dear thanks for your welcome :) im beginner in matlab, and need  helps to know the world of MATLAB

Comment: no problem, glad it helped. When you edit your original posts (OP) you can add an EDIT: or UPDATE: paragraph, without changing the concept of the original question (or title). That way people will know that you modify your question after receiving feedback.

Comment: dear, i have aquestion, could the localmax have a negative value?

Comment: yes, they can be negative as long as the negative value is `>` to its surrounding. This would  mean a peak in the negative axis of values. Try `plot` the signal, the peaks (maxima) on positive or negative axes will be visible.